# Proving $\cot {2 \theta} = \cfrac{A - C}{B}$, why do we set $x'$ and $y'$ equal to $0$? (Rotating conics)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When are $x'$ and $y'$ set equal to $0$ during this proof? My teacher said they were, but it seems to me like their coefficient is set equal to $0$ so they disappear. Please help.

This is the proof:

https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXoypizjW3WknFiJnKLwHCnL72vedxjQkDDP1mXWo6uco/wiki/Rotation_of_axes.html

Comment: You are right, the coefficient is set to zero.  Not sure what your teacher was saying.

Comment: Is the relevant line this? : "If $\theta$  is selected so that $\cot2\theta=(A-B)/C$ we will have $B'=0$ and the $x'y'$ term in equation (10) will vanish."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x'$ and $y'$ are not being set to zero in the proof. The theta is being chosen cleverly such that $B'$ is 0 thus the term $B'x'y'$ becomes zero and disappears. The $B'$ becomes zero because $\cos(2\theta) = \cos^2 \theta -\sin^2 \theta$ and $\sin (2 \theta) = 2 \sin \theta \cos \theta$ thus $$ \cot(2 \theta) = \frac{\cos(2\theta)}{\sin (2 \theta)} =\frac{\cos^2 \theta -\sin^2 \theta}{2 \sin \theta \cos \theta} $$ If you set this equal to $\frac{A-C}{B}$ then its pretty easy to see that $B'$ becomes zero.